# Error in updateOne pre hook unit test case in mongoose

Tags: mongoose, jestjs, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to cover the unit test case for my product category updateOne prehook method. In my schema for generalizing save and updateOne pre hook i declared `validateSaveHook()` methods and in that save prehook it work fine and i am able to write a unit test case. But in`updateOne` pre hook alone facing an issue. In that, i used `getupdate()` to get the value from mongoose query in code it works fine. While writing the Unit test case in terminal it throws error like `TypeError: this.getUpdate is not a function`. Can anyone please tell me what wrong in my test case code and how to overcome it?

**Test case**

```
 it('should throw error when sub_category false and children is passed.', async () => {
      // Preparing
  const next = jest.fn();
      const context = {
        op: 'updateOne',
        _update: {
          product_category_has_sub_category: false,
        },
      };
      // Executing
        await validateSaveHook.call(context, next);
        expect(next).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

**schama.ts:**

```
    export async function validateSaveHook(this: any, next: NextFunction) {
      let productCategory = this as ProductCategoryType;
      if (this.op == 'updateOne') {
        productCategory = this.getUpdate() as ProductCategoryType;
               if (!productCategory.product_category_has_sub_category && !productCategory['product_category_children']) {
          productCategory.product_category_children = [];
        }
      }
      if (productCategory.product_category_has_sub_category && isEmpty(productCategory.product_category_children)) {
        throwError("'product_category_children' is required.", 400);
      }
      if (!productCategory.product_category_has_sub_category && !isEmpty(productCategory.product_category_children)) {
        throwError("'product_category_children' should be empty.", 400);
      }
      next();
    }
export class ProductCategorySchema extends AbstractSchema {
  entityName = 'product_category';
  schemaDefinition = {
    product_category_has_sub_category: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: [true, 'product_category_has_sub_category is required.'],
    },

    product_category_children: {
      type: [Schema.Types.Mixed],
    },
  };

  indexes = ['product_category_name'];

  hooks = () => {
    this.schema?.pre('updateOne', validateSaveHook);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`validateSaveHook` expects a context to have `getUpdate` method. In case a context is mocked, it should provide this method:

```
const productCategory = {
  product_category_has_sub_category: ...,
  product_category_children: ...
};

const context = {
  getUpdate: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(productCategory),
  ...
```